# How can I add and use new column in abpfeature table and access it in boilerplate?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, aspnetboilerplate

I'm using asp.net zero build on boilerplate and I want to extend my table of feature, but I couldn't access feature table like other normal tables which I've created. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3):

I was facing your problem with another table `AuditLogs`, and I finally managed to solve it using EF Core features. You can find my issue and its solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65933752/7855321)

The solution is lying on the concept of inheritance in EF Core. Basically, you can create a new class namely "**ExtendedFeature**" derived from `AbpFeature`. Then you can add a new `DbSet` in the main context of your project and run the required migration. This will update your main table `AbpFeature` and add the new columns as well as the `Discriminator` columns which will be set automatically through the EF insert procedure.

If you create a new instance of `ExtendedFeature` the `discriminator` column will be set with **discriminator** otherwise it will be set with **Feature**. This will make your records distinguishable in the database.

For further information you can read this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/inheritance).