# how to extend settings in asp.net boilerplate

Tags: c#, asp.net, aspnetboilerplate

I'm using asp.net Zero which is based on asp.net boilerplate to develop our project.
I want to save our settings in AbpSettings table. But we have to add a filed named year.
when I get settings or insert settings, year filed is required. now I have extended Setting class and year filed is added to the database. But I have no idea about how to extend SettingManager.I have read the source code of asp.net boilerplate. It seems no way to do that.
Does anybody know how to do that? Thank you very much!

Comment: You can follow the instruction [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59982180/how-can-i-add-and-use-new-column-in-abpfeature-table-and-access-it-in-boilerplat/65983130#65983130)

Answer (score 1):

Here it shows how to extend AuditLogs, for the case of configurations it should be similar, [ASPNET Boilerplate, extending audit log](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65905255/aspnet-boilerplate-extending-audit-log)